# What is the default display property of the :before and :after pseudo-elements?

Tags: html, css

What is the default `display:` properties of :AFTER and :BEFORE pseudoelements after you specify `content`.

Is it `display: inline` or `display: inline-block`?

Could not find it in [default css values list](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_default_values.asp)

Example:

```css
div {
  border: solid 1px black;
  padding: 5px;
  }

div:before {
  content: "Before: Am I inline-block or inline?";
  color:red;
 }

div:after {
  content: "After: Am I Inline-block or inline?";
  color:green;
 }
```

```html
<div>Div 1</div>
<div>Div 2</div>
<div>Div 3</div>
<div>Div 4</div>
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements are [inline by default](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after).

As the [W3 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#before-after-content) says:

> In a :before or :after pseudo-element declaration, non-inherited
>   properties take their [initial values](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/about.html#initial-value).

And the [initial value of the display property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) is inline.