# Before pseudo element not showing

Tags: html, css

```css
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
}

div:before {
    content: "";
    width: 100px;
    height:30px;
    background: yellow;
}
```

Why isn't the before pseudo element showed above the div element when the position values (relative and absolute respectively) are not set?

Answer (score 9):

The [`::before`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before) and [`::after`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after) pseudo-elements are `display:inline` by default, which `width` and `height` will not affect.

You can set the pseudo-element to `display:block`.

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}

div:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

[View on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pt2gbk3c/)

Also see [What is the default display property of the :before and :after pseudo-elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47755989/what-is-the-default-display-property-of-the-before-and-after-pseudo-elements)

Answer (score 5):

The [default](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#before-after-content) display property of both `:before` and `:after` is inline, so your width and height declarations have no effect. Change it to block and bob's your uncle:

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}

div:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

**[jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/79usoj96/)**

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to add `position:absolute`

```css
 div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}

div:before {
  content: "";
  width: 100px;
  height:30px;
  background: yellow;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: But why is the position value needed?

Comment: Because pseudo elements always have a default `z-index` relative to their parent element, rather than `<html>`.  They will always appear 'behind' unless you override that behavior.

Comment: This also means that changing the z-index won't make it appear either? And why adding position absolute considers the width and height of the inline element?

Comment: @RobertC Your claim about `z-index` [doesn't appear to be the case](https://jsfiddle.net/pt2gbk3c/1/). Can you refer to any documentation?

Comment: My answer is specific to when `content` has no value though you could also set `display: block` for similar results.  Typically though these pseudo elements require additional positioning (as borders, offsets, etc) so `position:absolute` is more commonly used in my experience.