# How to use general siblings selector with ::after from its parent

Tags: css, css-selectors

I want to use the state from a checkbox to show and hide a ::after who is a general sibling from this.
I'm using this code, maybe you can help me with this issue. thanks.

```css
.form-check label {
  position: relative;
}

.form-check label:after {
  content: " ";
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: contain;
  right: -30px;
  top: 0;
  background-color: red;
}

.form-check [type="checkbox"]:checked~ ::after {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-check">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="example">
   <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="example">
   <span>Example</span>
   ::after
  </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're missing the essential properties – the `content`, `height`, `width` and `display` – from the CSS; if you add those then the posted code works:

```css
.form-check label {
  position: relative;
}

.form-check label:after {
  content: " ";
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: contain;
  right: -30px;
  top: 0;
  background-color: red;
}

.form-check [type="checkbox"]:checked~ ::after {
  /* forces the creation of the pseudo-element, without content
     it effectively doesn't exist: */
  content: '';
  /* because an empty string doesn't have any height, or width, by
     default we need to assign arbitrary non-zero values: */
  height: 1em;
  width: 1em;
  /* the ::before and ::after pseudo-elements are 'display: inline'
     by default, so to enable the element to accept its assigned width
     we make it 'display: inline-block' instead (though other values
     could be used if preferred): */
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-check">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="example">
   <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="example">
   <span>Example</span>
  </label>
</div>
```

It's worth noting that the supplied selector:

```
.form-check [type="checkbox"]:checked ~ ::after
```

will select all `::after` pseudo elements that follow the checked check-box; you may wish to modify the selector to reduce the likelihood of accidental matches, to:

```
.form-check [type="checkbox"]:checked ~ span::after
```

Which will match all `::after` pseudo-elements of `<span>` elements, or to:

```
.form-check [type="checkbox"]:checked + span::after
```

to match only the `::after` pseudo-element of the adjacent `<span>` element.

References:

- [`::after`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after).
- [Adjacent-sibling (`+`) combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator).
- [`content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content)
- [General-sibling (`~`) combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator).

Bibliography:

- "[What is the default display property of the [`::before`] and [`::after`] pseudo-elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47755989/what-is-the-default-display-property-of-the-before-and-after-pseudo-elements).

Answer (score 0):

There needs to be an element after the `<input>` in order to use a pseudo-element like that. In this case you've got a `<span>` there.

```
.form-check [type="checkbox"]:checked  ~  span::after {
    background-color: blue;
}
```