# how to create a circle around ordered <li> elements

Tags: css

Alright, this is really a simple question that I can't solve. I have an html document that looks like this:

```html
<ol>
  <li> item 1 </li>
  <li> item 2 </li>
  <li> item 3 </li>
</ol>
```

and the accompanying css looks like this:

```css
ol {
  list-style: none;
  counter-reset: li-counter;
}
ol li {
  counter-increment: li-counter;
}
ol li::before {
  content: counter(li-counter);
  color: #59cbbe;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;

  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 50px;

  padding: 4px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

and here is the [codepen](https://codepen.io/ctfrancia/pen/LYPaLXP)

I have tried following and modifying [this](https://css-tricks.com/custom-list-number-styling/) example, but wasn't able to get it. So I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9358882/how-to-make-a-circle-around-content-using-css) one as well. The main issue that I am having, when you look at the code pen is that the circles are not circles, they are always oblong and oval weather I use `30px` or `50%` is there something that I am missing. Sorry if this is a really simple answer, but, I am not that great at css.

Answer (score 7):

Well, you were on the right track. You just need to add `display: inline-block` to the pseudo element so the `width:20px; height:20px` will have effect. And so the pseudo-element will be a square + rounded border = circle.

[inline-block](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp) :

> Displays an element as an inline-level block container. The element
>   itself is formatted as an inline element, but you can apply height and
>   width values

As you can read up here [default display of pseudo-elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47755989/what-is-the-default-display-property-of-the-before-and-after-pseudo-elements) the `:before` pseudo-element has `display:inline` ( just like a span ) which does not accept width and height

from [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp) :

> Displays an element as an inline element (like `<span>`). Any height and
>   width properties will have no effect

```css
ol {
  list-style: none;
  counter-reset: li-counter;
}

ol li {
  counter-increment: li-counter;
}

ol li::before {
  content: counter(li-counter);
  color: #59cbbe;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;

  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 4px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li> item 1 </li>
  <li> item 2 </li>
  <li> item 3 </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: I would recommend setting width and height based on em so it scales with the font size.

Comment: awesome, thanks. Yea I thought I was around there but then whenever I tried to mess with the display, the elements got thrown all out of whack!

Comment: @JamesCoyle maybe it would be better with `rem` not `em`. So it will scale with the fontsize of the parent ( `li` ) but i think that is not needed in this case

Comment: @Ctfrancia Glad i could help ! Maybe you tried using `display:block` which would have a totally different effect. Don't forget to accept my answer, thanks ! :D

Comment: note that W3C is not W3Schools, you may want to edit that part to avoid confusion about refering to a non official specification

Comment: @TemaniAfif sorry about that.